# Exception error in exchangeElements procedure MASM

Tags: exception, x86, masm

I am trying to implement selection sort in MASM and I am having issues with swapping the two values.

I have tried to use a temp variable to swap the array elements but it kept giving me an error. I also ran out of the 6 main registers so I don't know what to do next.

```
sortList PROC
;include parameters - array (reference), request (value)
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
mov     edi, [ebp+12] ; @list in edi
mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; value of request in ecx

dec     ecx ; request - 1
mov     ebx, 0 ; "k"

firstLoop:
    mov     eax, ebx ; "i = k"

    mov     edx, ebx ; "j = k"
    inc     edx ; "j = k + 1"
    push    ecx ; pushed the first loop's counter
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; made the second loop's counter = request

    secondLoop:
        mov     esi, [edi + (edx * 4)]
        cmp     esi, [edi + (eax * 4)]
        jg      greater
        jle     lesser

        greater:
            mov     eax, edx
            inc     edx
            loop    secondLoop

        lesser:
            inc     edx
            loop    secondLoop

    push    edx
    push    esi
    push    [edi + (ebx * 4)] ; array[k]
    push    [edi + (eax * 4)] ; array[i]
    call    exchangeElements
    pop     [edi + (eax * 4)]
    pop     [edi + (ebx * 4)]
    pop     esi
    pop     edx
    pop     ecx ; set the 
    inc     ebx ; increment k in the first loop
    loop    firstLoop

pop     ebp
ret     8

sortList ENDP

exchangeElements PROC
     mov        esi, [edi + (eax * 4)] ; array[i]
     mov        edx, [edi + (ebx * 4)] ; array[k]
     mov        [edi + (eax * 4)], edx
     mov        [edi + (ebx * 4)], esi
     ret
exchangeElements ENDP
```

I expect my list to be sorted when I print it out.

Comment: `call` pushes a return address.  Those two `pop` instructions might work if you put them inline right after the `push`es.  That's very inefficient, though; when you run out of registers in an inner loop, go back to your outer loop and keep something rarely-used or read-only in memory.  This is what, Selection Sort?  You already have one of the values in ESI when you get to the swap, and don't need to keep reloading it.

Comment: For my assignment, I have to use a separate procedure to swap two array values. I changed my code a little bit so I don't pop the values out. My code still doesn't work however.

Comment: Your function is using the caller's registers as its args, not the values you pushed on the stack.  You need to pass pointers to a swap function, not values.  That would be easier if your main loop did pointer increments instead of integer indices, and also would save a register.  Also, `mov esi, [edx]` dereferences a value you just loaded as a pointer.  But you loaded it from the array, so it's an element to be sorted, not a pointer.

Comment: e.g. [How safe is this swap w/o pushing registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35397944) for a stack-args swap function you can call from C.

Comment: [How do you do a selection sort in MASM Assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22446331) has a MASM SelectionSort that calls a swap function (with register args), for bytes.  Easy enough to adapt for dwords, except that it uses AH and AL for byte temporaries.  Also related: [How does assembly do parameter passing: by value, reference, pointer for different types/arrays?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19858980)

Comment: I used the code from "How do you do a selection sort in MASM Assembly?" and also pushed registers to use them within the procedure. I don't get any errors now but the array is still not in order. I have updated the code above.